# My Proposed PhD supervisor is ignoring my email

Tags: graduate-admissions

I made a contact with a proposed PhD supervisor( Professor), everything went well and she forwarded the email between her and the department Research committee secretary that I have been shortlisted for studentship and recommended for Fellowship, in the email she sent to me, I observed a remark on my application file (my entrance requirement was indicated with FAILED) and I quickly asked her if it won't affect my admission, but she ignored it, a later found out that all applicant were initially categorized as a masters holder (I am a bsc holder) before screening that was the reason why for that). After, a couple of days, i asked her if I was later shortlisted for Fellowship but she ignored the message, though the admission offer will be released in March.

My questions are these;
Hope I have not create a doubt in her mind towards me as a result of my inquisitive nature?, hope this won't affect my admission offer and lastly, how can I build the relationship back because she used to reply my messaged often and appreciate my research proposal?

Comment: What is the time frame here? Not everyone answers email immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I mean how long has it been since you emailed? You say "ignored", but I'm wondering if that is accurate, or just "delayed".

Comment: If admission offers will be released in March, what is your reason for not waiting until March?

Comment: 5 days is a microsecond for graduate admissions. Committees need to meet, decisions have to be made, faculty/PIs need to hear official word back from these committees and department admins.....it all takes time.

Comment: Can't you call this person instead of writing emails? Is this a Chinese professor?

Answer (score 4):

This is obviously an important decision for you, and it's understandably making you anxious. However, you have to accept that the decision won't be made until March. Repeatedly contacting the folks making the decision, asking if they've decided won't help. They have a process they have to follow, and they can't make promises before they've completed that process. Sending repeated emails asking about the status of their decision could be annoying them (it would annoy me), but if they're reasonable, professional people it probably won't affect their decision on the position. However, no one can guarantee that. You just have to live with the uncertainty for a couple of months.

As long as your application is complete and accurate you should just put this aside until March. Find something else to keep yourself busy, or seek professional assistance if the anxiety is overwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have been peppering this professor with emails. Some might call this "inquisitive," others might call this "pestering." Not everyone answers their email within a day or two. Although not ideal, this is the way things are many times. Some professors receive literally hundreds of emails a day and filtering through them all is very time consuming. There were some semesters that I would teach 100+ students. Now stack all of the research and teaching assistants, department administrators, university administrators, society duties, colleagues, spam, etc on top of those emails from students. That's a lot of email to filter through in one day. Sometimes it would take me a few days to get back to a potential student who asked a question about their application.

Do you have any other points of contact in the department?

If the fellowship list does not come out until March, it actually seems that you have plenty of time still. This professor could be waiting to hear back from a chain of contacts in the department who make final decisions on things like fellowships.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have stopped pestering her with questions. But sir, hope my attitude (asking too much questions) leads to revoke of my admission, because base on the school policies any candidates that is recommended for the fellowship by the department is will be given studentship automatically if the fellowship fail. Thanks